# How to search using Vlookup and return initial value searched for if present

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two columns side by side. Old data. New Data. I am trying to use vlookup to see if a value in new data exists in old data then return the new data value in "Accounts Existing in Both" or blank if not found.

My current formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$A:$A,1,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

My formula now doesn't complete when dragged down and is not  populating cells that do actually exists. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check for unseen characters like spaces, that may be causing the cells not to be the same.

Comment: Tried that. I even removed the dash in the numbers to see if that would cause it but I still get the same result

Comment: Is calculation on automatic?

Comment: Run a `Len()` against both columns. If any number is other than 11 (based on sample data) you know where to clean out the extra stuff in the data. Also make sure both data sets are formatted identical - (i.e. - check for leading `'` in either column (especially col A).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the formula and as such The issue must be with the data, as to that we can only guess.  Try taking two that you think should be the same and do a straight comparison.  `=B3=A6` If they are the same it will return TRUE if not FALSE.

Comment: Another way to verify is to manually type some new test data

Comment: Try copying one cell in column B and press Ctrl+F to find that value in column A, are you able to find anything?

Comment: If you are looking to find if the number in old data matches old data why not just use a countif ? =COUNTIF(A2:A8,B2) in C would tell you if the number is in there or not.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think this is the problem, I have several 12 length columns, obviously was given very terrible data with unseen characters. Any shortcuts to remove things I cannot see? lol besides hand typing each of these 200 rows back out

Comment: @Lisa yes i am finding them in the first row, it is a problem with the data itself it seems

Comment: You try `=TRIM(CLEAN(A2))` in another column then copy/paste just the values.

Comment: @ScottCraner dude you are an absolute freaking life saver. That worked!! Thank you so much!! *Buys Beer*